Is there a generalization of second Mean Value Theorem of Integrals for non-monotonic class of functions?
The Second Mean value theorem of integrals states that:
If $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are integrable functions such that $g$ is monotone, then there exists $x_0\in [a,b]$ such that $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\ dx=g(a) \cdot \displaystyle\int_a^{x_0}f(x)\ dx+g(b) \cdot \int_{x_0}^bf(x)dx$.
Is there a generalization or similar result like this  for non-monotonic class of functions?

If $g$ is monotone increasing, right-continuous, and nonnegative, we could set $m := g(a)$ and $M := g(b)$ to obtain $m\leq g(x)\leq M$, i.e., $g$ is bounded and therefore integrable as $[a,b]$ is a finite interval. Define the function $$h(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$ on $[a,b]$ and note that $h$ absolutely continuous. Let $\nu$ be the Borel measure associated with $g$, and note that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Integration by parts then yields $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx = h(b)g(b) - h(a)g(a) - \int_a^b h\,\mathrm d\nu.$$ Let $L := \inf_{x\in[a,b]}h(x)$ and $U:=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}h(x)$. Then $L\leq h\leq U$ and hence $$L\big(g(b) - g(a)\big) \leq \int_a^b h\,\mathrm d\nu \leq U\big(g(b) - g(a)\big).$$ Since $g$ is monotone, we can only have $g(a) = g(b)$ if $g$ is constant. But if $g$ is constant, the result follows immediately. So, without loss of generality, $g(a)\neq g(b)$ and we can divide by $g(b) - g(a)$ to obtain $$L\leq\frac{\int_a^b h\,\mathrm d\nu}{g(b) - g(a)}\leq U.$$ Since $h$ is continuous, there exists a $\xi\in[a,b]$ such that $$h(\xi) = \frac{\int_a^b h\,\mathrm d\nu}{g(b) - g(a)},$$ i.e., $$h(\xi)\big(g(b) - g(a)\big) = \int_a^b h\,\mathrm d\nu.$$ This gives $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx = h(b)g(b) - h(a)g(a) - h(\xi)g(b) + h(\xi)g(a) = g(a)\int_a^\xi f(x)\,\mathrm dx + g(b)\int_\xi^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Now that we know what are the crucial parts, we could see if we can modify something:

Non-negativity: We needed it to show that $g$ is integrable and for this inequality $$L\big(g(b) - g(a)\big) \leq \int_a^b h\,\mathrm d\nu \leq U\big(g(b) - g(a)\big)$$ to hold. Furthermore, non-negativity implied that $\nu\geq 0$. If $g$ changes signs (assuming monotony), then the inequalities may reverse. So we could just drop this assumption.
Right-continuity: This was necessary for $\nu$ to exist and for the integration by parts formula to hold. An integration by parts formula also holds if $g$ is the pointwise average of a functions left- and a right-continuous versions. Dropping this assumption is not possible for this proof. But it is possible: for example, you could approximate $g$ by step functions (which is possible as $g$ is measurable) or you could use the Rieman-Stieltjes integral, which exists if $f$ is continuous. You could also "cheat" and just consider the class of functions for which the Lebesgue/Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $h$ exists and the integration by parts formula holds.
Monotony: We needed it to show that $g$ is bounded (and hence integrable) and for $\nu$ to exist. Furthermore, monotony implies that $g(b) - g(a)>0$ (or negative if $g$ is decreasing). We can't drop the monotony assumption entirely, but we could weaken it a bit by assuming that $g$ is of bounded variation (i.e., the difference of two monotone functions).

